# Is using async when no indepent work can be done useful / worth it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

The MSDN async example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) gives the following example:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
    DoIndependentWork();

    string urlContents = await getStringTask;
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Basically, from my understanding, you can do independent work between calling an async method and using its result. However, in the example they add that

> If AccessTheWebAsync doesn't have any work that it can do between
>   calling GetStringAsync and awaiting its completion, you can simplify
>   your code by calling and awaiting in the following single statement.

```
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();
```

Now, assuming a synchronous `client.GetString()` method exists and there's no independent work that can be done between, does writing something like this give any benefits whatsoever? Are these two calls different by any means in this situation?:

```
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync();
```

vs

```
string urlContents = client.GetString();
```

Comment: 1st one will execute method not on UI thread while 2nd will call it on UI thread which will block UI

Comment: Async is usually about freeing up the thread while waiting for IO. It may not improve the performance  if you are executing a single thread, but on something like a webserver not wasting resources while waiting for db calls or file access lets you use less resources.

Comment: So it basically frees the current thread until the e.g. DB answers?

Comment: The independent work idea is a very rare usage of async IO in fact. Almost all usages are to save threads and to unblock the UI in client apps.

Comment: Unless you count responding to user input (or to other web requests in the case of web applications) as "independent work" in which case it would be very rare not to have independent work to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these two calls different by any means in this situation?

Yes.

The first one is *asynchronous*; this means that the calling thread is freed up to do other things while `GetStringAsync` is in progress.

The second one is *synchronous*; this means that the calling thread is blocked while `GetString` is in progress.

On the client side, the primary benefit of asynchronous code is *responsiveness*. That is, the UI thread is freed up to respond to user input.

On the server side, the primary benefit of asynchronous code is *scalability*. That is, the request thread is freed up to respond to other requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these two calls different by any means in this situation?:

**Yes** they are different.

The first one causes the method to be executed not on UI thread which will cause your application to remain responsive, while in second one that's not the case, and if method execution takes more time, UI will remain blocked, and user won't be able to interact with application.

```
string urlContents = await client.GetStringAsync(); // non blocking call

string urlContents = client.GetString(); // this is blocking current Thread
```

Comment: Assuming the method takes 3 seconds to return, the cursor will stop on the first line for 3 seconds, just like on the 2nd line. Care to explain exactly is it non blocking?

Comment: in both cases it will stop for 3 seconds, the difference is just 1st will not execute it on UI thread while 2nd will execute on UI thread, so if it takes 3 seconds User will not able to do any other interaction with your application

Answer (score 0):

The first one will wait until the client returns and block anything else before moving on to the next line.

The second one will wait until the client returns before moving on to the next line, but in the mean time *other threads* can do work that doesn't depend on the result.